# page by sending e-mail

Tags: email, wiki, mediawiki

hi
i built an wiki site with media wiki
i would like to know if it is posible to configure a way that i can build a page on my wiki by sending an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3AEmailToWiki